# What do I need to add a virtual IPsec adapter?

Tags: command-line, networking, routing, ipsec, iproute

I'm trying to set up an IPsec connection manually from the console with iproute2.
What I need is a virtual interface (at best, a virtual IP address could also be sufficient) that IPsec-transforms everthing ingressing (ESP/TUNNEL MODE) and hands it over to eth0 (on my system called em1).
On the other set a peer takes the packet from its own eth deciphers it and hands it over to a virtual interface a the other side. So I want do establish a "normal" IPsec tunnel.

I've got no problem with the policy and SA, and configuring that was easy using the normal ethernet addresses of the systems in transport mode, i.e.

```
ip xfrm policy add src 198.51.100.1 dst 198.51.100.2 dir out tmpl proto esp
ip xfrm state  add src 198.51.100.1 dst 198.51.100.2 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0011
ip xfrm state  add src 198.51.100.2 dst 198.51.100.1 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0022
```

and an adversary configuration on the peer works quite well.

Now I tried to set up a virtual IP and a route to the other system with

```
ip address add 10.0.0.0 dev em1
ip route add to 10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.1
```

and again vice versa on the other side. This again works well. Then I altered  the IPsec policy and SA to

```
ip xfrm policy add src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 dir out tmpl src 198.51.100.1 dst 198.51.100.2 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm state  add src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0011
ip xfrm state  add src 10.0.0.2 dst 10.0.0.1 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0022
```

When I now try to `tcping` the peer I get no answer and `setkey -PD` tells me, that the security policy was never triggered. Now I'm trying to fabricate a working virtual interface to handle the IPsec tunnel, but I don't know how to bind it to the physical interface and how I get the kernel to apply the security policy.

It is vital for me that I can solve this with iproute2, as I ultimately want to do this out of a C++ program and I have already the appropriate classes that drop Netlink commands the same style the `ip` command does (what I can do with `ip`, I also can do within my code). In fact, the first part already works out of my program and I want to use the same Netlink API functions for the rest.

*Update*
I figured out that the state needed to be set up with the tunnel addresses so the working SAs are

```
ip xfrm state  add src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0011
ip xfrm state  add src 10.0.0.2 dst 10.0.0.1 spi 24501 proto esp enc des 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0022
```

while the policy remains the same. Now the policy is triggered and I see a transformed packet on a sniffing port. Also iptables on the other machine blocked the packet and I disabled it for testing.

So, the one direction seems to work now, but I still get no answer. I also don't know if the problem is *yet* somehow the transform, the routing or the interface part. My prefered solution would still be one including a virtual interface, but I don't have any idea how to bind it to a physical one, let alone if the transform would work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally what you use is a tunnel, created using `ip tunnel add`. The tunnel device gives you a virtual device that encapsulates IP packets inside other IP packets. Then the encapsulated packet can be encrypted using IPsec.

For example, you can create a [GRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation) tunnel using:

```
ip tunnel add mytunnel mode gre remote 198.51.100.2
ip addr add 10.0.0.1 peer 10.0.0.2/31 dev mytunnel
```

Then you can configure IPSec to encrypt GRE packets (either in general, or just to that destination).